# Blurry wallpaper of downloaded image even after using image compatible to screen resolutions

Tags: display-resolution, desktop-background

Here are screenshots which will help to figure out the problem. Blurry desktop background can be seen in the first image of screen resolution in the background.

[image: Screen resolutions]
<sup>**Screen resolutions**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

[image: Setting wallpaper]
<sup>**Setting wallpaper**</sup>

Comment: Blurry desktop background can be seen from 1st image of screen resolution in the backgrond

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have downloaded the low-resolution thumbnail from the google images search, not the original image. You need to click on the image and choose "view original image" and download that one.